# Multiple Linked Lists

Tags: c, list

I am new to C and it's kind of rocket science at the moment for me, so I am trying to understand it better.

I have the following linked list implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "linked_list.h"

struct Node *head = NULL;
struct Node *current = NULL;

//display the list
void printList() {
    struct Node *ptr = head;
    printf("\n[ ");

    //start from the beginning
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("(%d,%d) ", ptr->key, ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    printf(" ]");
}

//insert link at the first location
void insertFirst(int key, int data) {
    //create a link
    struct Node *link = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    link->key = key;
    link->data = data;

    //point it to old first Node
    link->next = head;

    //point first to new first Node
    head = link;
}

//delete first item
struct Node* deleteFirst() {

    //save reference to first link
    struct Node *tempLink = head;

    //mark next to first link as first 
    head = head->next;

    //return the deleted link
    return tempLink;
}

//is list empty
bool isEmpty() {
    return head == NULL;
}

int length() {
    int length = 0;
    struct Node *current;

    for (current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
        length++;
    }

    return length;
}

//find a link with given key
struct Node* find(int key) {
    //start from the first link
    struct Node* current = head;

    //if list is empty
    if (head == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    //navigate through list
    while (current->key != key) {

        //if it is last Node
        if (current->next == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
        else {
            //go to next link
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

    //if data found, return the current Link
    return current;
}

//delete a link with given key
struct Node* delete(int key) {
    //start from the first link
    struct Node* current = head;
    struct Node* previous = NULL;

    //if list is empty
    if (head == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    //navigate through list
    while (current->key != key) {

        //if it is last Node
        if (current->next == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }

        //store reference to current link
        previous = current;
        //move to next link
        current = current->next;
    }

    //found a match, update the link
    if (current == head) {
        //change first to point to next link
        head = head->next;
    }
    else {
        //bypass the current link
        previous->next = current->next;
    }

    return current;
}

void sort() {
    int size = length();
    int k = size;

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++, k--) {
        struct Node *current = head;
        struct Node *next = head->next;

        for (int j = 1; j < k; j++) {
            if (current->data > next->data) {
                int temp_data = current->data;
                current->data = next->data;
                next->data = temp_data;

                int temp_key = current->key;
                current->key = next->key;
                next->key = temp_key;
            }

            current = current->next;
            next = next->next;
        }
    }
}
```

I realized though, that I can only make one linked list with this code, in its own main function.

I need multiple linked lists (of different types, like in Java for example `new LinkedList<T>`) so I created a header for use in different classes.

```
#pragma once
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    int key;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

void printList();
void insertFirst(int key, int data);
struct Node* deleteFirst();
bool isEmpty();
struct Node* find(int key);
struct Node* delete(int key);
void sort();
```

However I am still not sure how exactly to make it work for more than one linked list? Any ideas?

Comment: Create multiple `head` variables, one for each list. And then pass it to the functions. Or use a structure for the list as well (my advice), passing (pointers) to the structure to the list functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can you post some code if possible so I can understand it better? Thanks

Comment: This is a very good example of why you should not use globals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a structure that contains head and current. Pass that into the functions as a parameter as well

i.e.

```
typedef struct {
   struct Node *head;
   struct Node *current;
} MyList;

MyList *CreateMyList() {
   MyList * list= malloc(sizeof(MyList));
   list->current = list->head = NULL;
   return list;
}


void insertFirst(MyList *list, int key, int data) {
    //create a link
    struct Node *link = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

   link->key = key;
   link->data = data;

   //point it to old first Node
   link->next = list->head;
   //point first to new first Node
   list->head = link;
}
```

I leave the other functions as an excise to the reader

Comment: please note i removed the cast off malloc

Comment: That worked fine. Any way to make it work with different data types, not just ints? I need to put structs in the lists

Comment: Move to C++ - or use void pointers for the datatype - I would not recommend that later

Comment: The problem is this is an exercise for university and I need to use C. I have multiple structs (students, teachers etc.) that need to be added into a list

Answer (score 2):

Here the code used the global variables making the method not usable again. So all that you can do is, rewrite the code avoiding the use of global variables. Whatever global variables are used by these methods just pass them accordingly to the methods. That way you can reuse it.